# Node.js MongoDB Sockets closed error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently making a login system for my NodeJS application. However, I get a strange error from MongoDB whenever I try retrieving a collection.

**Error Message**

```
[MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed]
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'server localhost:27017 sockets closed'
```

Heres my code to connect to my db

```
    var username = req.body.user.username;
    var password = req.body.user.password;

    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myDb", function(err, db){
        assert.equal(null, err);

        var collection = db.collection("accounts");
        collection.findOne({"username": username}, function(err, item){
            console.log(item);
            console.log(err);
        });

        db.close();
    });
```

Is anyone able to see where Ive gone wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are closing yourself the database before the find query is ever done (it is an async method). Remove that `db.close()` or move it on the `findOne` callback.

```
var username = req.body.user.username;
var password = req.body.user.password;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myDb", function(err, db){
    assert.equal(null, err);

    var collection = db.collection("accounts");
    collection.findOne({"username": username}, function(err, item){
        console.log(item);
        console.log(err);
        db.close();
    });


});
```

By the way, you will have very poor performance by connecting/closing the DB connexion with each query and you should avoid doing that: connect once on the app startup and close the db on app close

Comment: :0 Thanks so much! "Spams the Accept Button" :)